# Different Background Color of div by Selecting nth:child of span using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors

I am trying to change the BackGround color of div or span using jQuery. I want to highlight the values of the second span with div having same class name. Where value be like 75,40,54 with different color, but it highlights all div with green.

```
<div class="containerbox">
    <div id="centerbox1" style= "min-width:25%; max-height: 90px">
      <p><div class="value ok" data-color="25">
        <span style="color: #fff ;font-weight:bold; font-size:36px">kk</span>
      <span style="color: #fff ;font-weight:bold; font-size:36px">75</span>
      <br>
     
      </div></p>
  </div>

      <div id="centerbox1" style= "min-width:25%; max-height: 90px">
     <p> <div class="value ok" data-color="100">
        <span  style="color: #fff ;font-weight:bold; font-size:36px">rr</span>
      <span  style="color: #fff ;font-weight:bold; font-size:36px">40</span>
      <br>
     
      </div></p>
  </div>


      <div id="centerbox1" style= "min-width:25%; max-height: 90px">
      <p><div class="value ok" data-color="25">
        <span  style="color: #fff ;font-weight:bold; font-size:36px">ee</span>
      <span  style="color: #fff ;font-weight:bold; font-size:36px">54</span>
      <br>
     
      </div></p>
        </div>
 
    </div>
```

My javascript below with nth selector:

```
    $('.value.ok').each(function() {
     var val = parseInt( $('.value span:nth-child(even)').text()),
      //alert(val);
        dd = parseInt( $('.value span:nth-child(2)').text());
        alert(dd);
    var d = 50;
    var e = 65;
    if (val < d) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
     if (val > d && val < e) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
     }

     if (val > e && val <= dd) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
    }
    });
```

If i remove one span from each div it works well but not with having extra span.

My javascript below without nth selector

```
$('.value.ok').each(function() {
var val = parseInt( $(this).text()),
//alert(val);
    dd = parseInt( $('.value.ok').text());
    //alert(dd);
    var d = 50;
    var e = 65;
if (val < d) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
}
if (val > d && val < e) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
}

if (val > e && val <= dd) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
}
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $(this) to refer to the current object and then use find() function to get your element

```js
    $('.value.ok').each(function() {
     var val = parseInt( $(this).find('span:nth-child(even)').text()),
      //alert(val);
        dd = parseInt( $(this).find('span:nth-child(2)').text());
        alert(dd);
    var d = 50;
    var e = 65;
    if (val < d) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
     if (val > d && val < e) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
     }

     if (val > e && val <= dd) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containerbox">
    <div id="centerbox1" style= "min-width:25%; max-height: 90px">
      <p><div class="value ok" data-color="25">
        <span style="color: #fff ;font-weight:bold; font-size:36px">kk</span>
      <span style="color: #fff ;font-weight:bold; font-size:36px">75</span>
      <br>
     
      </div></p>
  </div>

      <div id="centerbox1" style= "min-width:25%; max-height: 90px">
     <p> <div class="value ok" data-color="100">
        <span  style="color: #fff ;font-weight:bold; font-size:36px">rr</span>
      <span  style="color: #fff ;font-weight:bold; font-size:36px">40</span>
      <br>
     
      </div></p>
  </div>


      <div id="centerbox1" style= "min-width:25%; max-height: 90px">
      <p><div class="value ok" data-color="25">
        <span  style="color: #fff ;font-weight:bold; font-size:36px">ee</span>
      <span  style="color: #fff ;font-weight:bold; font-size:36px">54</span>
      <br>
     
      </div></p>
        </div>
 
    </div>
```

Comment: ok, so is there any way that > *").not("span:nth-child(1)").each(function() will not work instead .find (element)

Comment: I dont think with your html sctructure. You can validate my answer if u find it usefull :) @SandeepTete